# time differences between multiple lists

Tags: python, list, datetime, time

I have a few different lists: `scan` which is a list of different time stamps and `focal` which is a list of a few different time stamps repeated, and `interval` which tells me at what indices the time stamps in `focal` change. The goal is to calculate the difference of the `scan` timestamps for each one in `focal`. I am a little stuck on how to use `interval` in a while loop for the calculations. Here is what I have so far:

```
def scanDuration():
    scan = scanTimeFMT()
    focal = startTimeFMT()
    focal.pop(0)
    interval = []
    times = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(scan):
        whole = scan[i]
        time = str(whole[11:])
        times.append(time)
        i += 1

    j = 1
    while j < len(focal)-1:
        if focal[j] != focal[j+1]:
            interval.append(j+1)
            j += 1
        else:
            j += 1
```

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is scanTimeFMT ?

Comment: Is `interval` supposed to be the intersection of `scan` and `focal`? This looks like a problem that might be better solved with sets: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: So what exactly do you want to append to interval? An index in `focal` list looks like not it?

Comment: What output do you want from `scanDuration()`? It'd be helpful to have sample input and the output that you want to generate.

Comment: Also note, this use of `while` seem unnecessary, esp. in the first look where `for` would be more concise esp. since you do not use the index value for anything but the iteration itself. At the bottom, you increment `j` in any case... just drop the `else` and move it one indentation level to the left. ;)